# Naming convention for margin top and bottom on images

Tags: html, css

Instead of adding inline styles for margin top and bottom for images, I'd like to come up with a simple naming convention for their class.

Not every image would have a margin top and bottom.

- Some images I would like to have a 40px margin on the top and bottom
- Other images I would like to have a 30px margin on the top and bottom

What's a good naming convention for my css for these types of styles?

Want to avoid always having to put:

```
<p style="margin: 40px 0">
```

Comment: It's up to you, use whatever makes the most sense to you.

Comment: If possible don't choose class names based on the number of pixels, but on the type it represents. That said, we don't have the context needed to make up a good name, and even then it would still be opinion-based.

Comment: Think about *why* some things get a different margin. In CSS, we don't use class names that describe the content of the CSS e.g. we don't create a class called `blue` because when a redesign calls for the use of red instead we end up with `.blue{color:red;}` - and how confusing is that!

Comment: Try to go with type of element rather than css properties of element. like .smallImage, .bigImage, .detailsImage etc..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google started using "[Display Density](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/1670219?hl=en)" in Gmail in [November 2011](http://gmailblog.blogspot.com/2011/11/changing-information-density-in-gmails.html), which they named "comfortable," "cozy" and "compact."

You could mimic their naming convention to establish class names based on how much top and bottom space you give the images.

```
.comfortable { margin: 40px 0; }
.cozy { margin: 30px 0; }
.compact { margin: 10px 0; } /* or whatever you want */
```